# is it possible to see the preview of the layout that made only by java?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm gonna read an open source api and edit it's layout but there isn't any xml layout file and all layout is define in it's own activity by java 
is there any way to see the preview of activities layout ?

Answer (score 3):

No there is not. The only way is to run the app and see what you get.

Actually, what you could try is to create a **custom view** class of your own (e.g. inheriting from FrameLayout) and put all layout building code into that custom view. Then you can create a layout xml file that would only consist of your custom view class. This will show you the layout. You might need to add some checks using `isInEditMode()` to avoid crashes when the code would do something that is not possible in the layout viewer.